# Flutter dynamic growing of flex boxes

Tags: flutter, dart, layout

I have a Row with three elements:

1. A Text which can be arbitrary short or long (called text in code)
2. A Wrap of elements which can be arbitrary short or long (called wrap in code)
3. An element of fixed size at the end (called fixed in code)

If it is possible to fit everything in one line, I want that all elements are displayed without any wrapping: [image]

Only once it does not fit in one line, elements are allowed to wrap. I don't particularly care in that case, which element wraps first. I think it would be optimal to minimize the resulting vertical height, but this aspect is not that important to me.

My current code is:

```
return Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween, children: [
  Flexible(child: Text(text, softWrap: true,)),
  Flexible(child: wrap),
  fixed,
]);
```

Unfortuantely the text and wrap element, each always take up exactly 50% of the available space in this case (due to the flex weight being 1 by default). So if either element takes more than 50% space it starts wrapping although it could take space from the other if that one is small.

How can I achieve no wrapping as long as it can be layout without wrapping?

Answer (score 0):

What if you used Wrap instead of Row:

```flutter
Row(
  children: [
    Wrap(
      children: [
        Text('text')
        wrap,
      ]
    ),
    fixed
  ],
),
```